# Reading and searching long man pages

Tags: search, man

I finally got fed up when wanting to read about *bash*'s `read` and it's `-s` option with `man bash`. I found the right spot eventually (around line 4500), but it was a frustrating as usual, since both `/read` and even `/\s-s\s` searches have way too many matches.

So, the question is: How can I read long man pages efficiently, or get same information in other ways, *locally*? As a specific example, how to reach the relevant documentation after seeing `read -s pwd` in a shell script? A good answer could be a shell script snippet, or hint about some tool and how it is used, or something else entirely, as long as it helps in finding the right spot to read.

Note: I'm not tagging with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) because I want the question to be about man page reading in general, even though that quite possibly is the most commonly encountered humongous man page.

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because it may be outside your requirements but: when I need to read a long `man` page I use a little script i leave on my upper panel.   http://www.yuugian.com/demo/gkman.txt  Share and enjoy

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer either ;) because it's indeed about `bash` itself: just like you, I too mostly need the `SHELL BUILTINS` part of the manual, which is at about line __3500__. So knowing this, the next time I would just say `man bash` and then go down 66 percent, by typing __`66%`__, then a few times __PgDn__ and I'm there. Though I chose 66 because it can be memorized as __"Route 66"__, it is actually a little more than that, albeit not so easy to memorize unless it is the beginning of your phone #, etc. :) At least the "Route 66" is universal and known worldwide.

Answer (score 38):

For quickly getting help on a Bash builtin, use `help`:

```
help read
```

is what you want.

For man-page-like formatting, use

```
help -m read
```

or, even better,

```
help -m read | less
```

If you still insist on looking for it in the man page, I find what quickly gets me to a command's explanation is

```
/^\s*read [[]
```

This works because when a command is first explained, its name is indented slightly from the start of the line. In the particular case of `read`, this takes a little browsing before you get to the actual `read` documentation because (for obvious reasons) the word "read" is repeated a lot throughout the man page. The [[] means to match a [ which usually precedes optional parameters. (I usually leave out /^\s* and simply do /<built-in command> [[])

**Another alternative**

If you don't mind the format change, you can convert your man page to a DVI or PDF file:

```
man -T dvi bash >bash.dvi
```

or

```
man -T ps bash | ps2pdf - bash.pdf # Requires the Ghostscript suite for ps2pdf
```

Of course, given a DVI or PDF document, you can then do a text search easily.

Comment: Hmm, that `help` is great, I wonder how I've never heard of it... `ps2pdf` is not that useful since it can't (apparently) create index of any kind.

Comment: @hyde Not sure what you mean by creating an index, but have you heard of [ptx](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92730/usr-bin-ptx-can-you-provide-a-use-case-or-two/93047#93047)?

Comment: Index or Table of Contents, that "ptx" sounds exactly like what I meant.

Comment: Another, even simpler alternative is to do 'man bash > bashman.txt'. Then you can just open bashman.txt in (another) window in your text editor and use all of it's commands for finding what you want. You can even edit the file to add tags for the sections you refer to most often. Making bashman.txt read-only helps so you don't modify it by accident in your editor.

Comment: You can also open man pages in the browser of your choice and use all of its tools. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/339255/make-man-pages-open-in-a-web-browser?newsletter=1&nlcode=17739|f2f3

Comment: The help command is indeed really cool, pdf text search is bad, regex is much better - steeper learning curve, but worth every minute spent, eventually.

Answer (score 9):

**Approach 1**

`man bash` then `/read \[` then `/-s`

**Approach 2**

You may try an open source tool for explaining command-line arguments called [explainshell](http://www.explainshell.com/).

It can be used locally. Read documentation on https://github.com/idank/explainshell

Caveats: Usually works, but only with commands found in Ubuntu's manpage repository

In your case, it cannot recognize `-s` switch in `read -s pwd`.

**Approach 3**

I have found another tool that seems promising but it does not work on my system.

[explain: Short Documentation for Unix Commands](https://web.archive.org/web/20120131161939/http://www.brettdaniel.com/archives/2009/11/07/035711/)

Comment: With approach 1, you can do `/-s\b` to avoid hits like `--some-other-command` (while still finding strings such as `-s,`, which you wouldn't get if you searched for `/-s` with a space).

Answer (score 8):

What I usually do in this case is just run `man`, search for the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` heading, then search for the builtin, i.e.

```
man bash
/^SHELL BUILTIN
/  read
```

however, in bash you can do

```
help read
```

or, depending on the system, either of

```
man 1 read
man bash-builtins
```

In general, I have a script called [`he`](https://github.com/mikelward/scripts/blob/master/he) ("short help") to do this.  You would run it like this:

```
he bash read
```

Comment: FYI, I renamed `desc` to `he`.  https://github.com/mikelward/scripts/blob/master/he

Answer (score 3):

There is no generic way to finding information in a man page, any more than there is a generic way of finding information in a book. It depends on what you're looking for.

When you're looking for information about a shell builtin, you can search for the builtin at the beginning of a line save for indentation, and followed by a space: search for `^ *read␣` (e.g. type `/^ *read␣` <kbd>Enter</kbd>) (`␣` is a space). This works with dash, pdksh, mksh and bash. Zsh's man page is split so you need to read the `zshbuiltins` man page. Ksh93 has special symbols before the names of some builtins, you need to search for `^ *†*␣` in UTF-8 or `^ *-*␣` in ASCII. There are a couple of false positives but this will get you quickly to the right line. Searching for `^ *read($| [-[])` reduces the amount of false positives.

You can speed up the search by telling your pager where you want to go. For example `PAGER='less "+/^ *read \["' man bash` opens the bash man page on the description of the `read` builtin. You can make this a function:

```
man-builtin () {
  PAGER="less '+/^ *$1(\$|\\[|-)'" man ${SHELL##*/}
}
```

Comment: In the `mksh` manpage, `/  read ` (two spaces, command name, one space) usually finds the right spot (this is a trick I use myself, and is quick to type). Thanks for asking about it; I’ll put making (somewhat) separate references for all utilities included with mksh on my TODO.

Comment: @mirabilos `/  read ` tends to have a lot of false positives when your man implementation justifies the text.

Comment: Agreed. Even more reason to really split off the builtin documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To jump directly to the SHELL BUILTINS COMMANDS section of the bash man page, I define the following alias in my `$HOME/.bash_aliases` file.

```
alias man-builtin="man -P 'less -p ^SHELL\ BUILTIN\ COMMANDS' bash"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around to creating a bash function for the purpose. This snippet can be for example pasted at the end of `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
manfind() {
  # required args
  test "$1" -a "$2" || return 1                  

  # create temp file and get its name
  local tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/manfindXXXXXX) || return 1
  ( # subshell for trap
    trap "rm $tmp" EXIT

    # grep all matching lines with line numbers and pipe them to dialog
    if man "$1" |                   # get the whole man page
      grep -n "^\s*$2" |            # grep for the search string, with line nums
      sed 's/:/\n/' |               # replace line num separator with newline for dialog
      cut -c-70  |                  # cut long lines to nice length
      xargs -d'\n' -n 999999 \
        dialog --output-fd 3 --menu "Select line to go to" 0 0 0 3>$tmp -- 1 '(start of man page)'
    then
      # selected line number is now in $tmp, get man page and
      # use vim in read only mode to view it at right line
      man "$1" | vim -R +"$(< $tmp)" -
    else
      # cancel selected from dialog
      exit 1
    fi
  )
}
```

Comments explain a bit about what it does. The default search string in particular searches given word from the beginning of lines, skipping initial space. Examples:

```
# find every line which starts with 'read' followed by space
manfind bash 'read '
# research bash subshells
manfind bash '.*subshell'
```

Note: This script has no concept of man page sections... I'll see if I tweak that later, but setting `MANSECT` environment variable of *man* helps.

Comment: You might want to add a trap to clean up the temporary file: `trap 'rm -f "$tmp"'`

Comment: This looks very complicated. I haven't fully read what your script does, but wouldn't `man "$1" | vim -R - "+/$2"` do something similar?

Comment: @Gilles I that would go to first occurrence of `$2`, so no.

Comment: @l0b0 Changed cleanup to use `trap`. I didn't find a clean way to do it in a function without creating a subshell though.

Comment: @hyde Adapt the regex to what you're doing, of course. My point was about using `+/REGEX`

Comment: You might want to trap the default signals (i.e., not specify `EXIT`) to handle for example Ctrl-C.

Comment: @l0b0 Are you sure that's useful? `EXIT` seems to trap any exit, for example: `(trap 'echo EXITTRAP' EXIT; echo "Press ^C" ; read foo)`

Comment: @Gilles My fingers are really itching to simplify this, especially the pipe which looks like trying to do things completely __butt-backwards__ (to use a US phrase) :)) Like getting the buzz saw from the basement just to cut a 1"-diameter round timber ;))

Comment: @syntaxerror If you want to tidy the script up (without changing functionality or introducing other scripting languages, though I suppose I would be ok with *awk*), feel free to edit... :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer another alternative, if you prefer using a web browser which allows you to easily search through the current page, you can use something like [man.cgi](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi) used at freeBSD.org which also lets you view man pages from different systems to see how they differ. I have seen similar on other sites so expect there are other variations around.

The help link under apropos offers some info to get a copy of the script to put on your own server with links to download the man page collections.

Answer (score 0):

Putting together the pieces from the other discussion [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/can-i-get-individual-man-pages-for-the-bash-builtin-commands) here's a quick function you can leave in your `.bashrc` that will get you directly to the built-in (if it exists). Otherwise it opens `man` as normal:

```bsh
man() {
    case "$(/bin/bash -c 'type -t '"$1")" in 
        builtin)
            LESS=+?"^       $1 " command -p man bash
            ;;
        *)
            command -p man $@
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From any Linux distro you should be able to use `info bash` if you want to have separate paragraphs by type of action where the information are identical to man pages.