# How to highlight some text on a man page?

Tags: man, gnome-terminal, highlighting

I find the manuals very difficult to read using the terminal. Is there a way to highlight specific text on the terminal? I tried piping to `gedit` using `man man | gedit`, but it opens a blank file instead.

Perhaps there's some way to find text within a man page and have it highlighted?

Comment: Take a look at this U&L Q&A: [Colors in Man Pages](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages)

Comment: @slm, thanks, but that is syntax highlighting, different from what I want - highlighting specific text.

Comment: Just hit `/` in the man page and then whatever you want to search for and `enter`. Hitting `n` moves to the next match and matches should be highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Dumping to clear text

You can use this technique to dump a man page out to a text file.

```
$ man -P cat ls > manpg_ls.txt
```

The above technique is just changing what pager `man` uses. Here we're telling it to use the `cat` command instead. We then get the man page for the `ls` command dumped to a file in clear text.

#### Example

Here's the first 10 lines of the `ls` man page.

```
$ man -P cat ls | head -10
LS(1)                                                              User Commands                                                             LS(1)



NAME
       ls - list directory contents

SYNOPSIS
       ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

#### Searching

Another approach is to use alternative pager commands and functions to search through man pages. Several techniques are covered in this U&L Q&A, titled: [Reading and searching long man pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/reading-and-searching-long-man-pages/).

Comment: Thank you. I managed to find a simpler solution after pressing h for help. Sharing it here with everyone.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - re-read the link I gave you, the `/some` along with other techniques is covered over there.

Comment: Indeed, I have to read that post the third time to realise that my answer could be found in the question itself because I misinterpret `read` to be some command.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a much simpler solution:

Once you have entered man page, type:

```
/some text
```

It does a case-insensitive search and highlight all occurrences of "some text". You can just <kbd>page up</kbd> or <kbd>page down</kbd> to scroll through the entire man page after that.

Comment: And if GNU less is your pager, you can type a Ctrl-K after the `/` to do the search in "Keep position" mode - it will highlight the matches without jumping ahead.