# less '+>' /path/to/file

Tags: less

So [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) [mentioned in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14752077#14752077) that:

```
less '+>' /path/to/file
```

can be used with `less` in order to view a file in reverse. I've never seen it before.

I'm curious - what's going on with the `+>` operator in the title? Is this  `less` specific syntax? Can it be used otherwise? Are there similar operators I should probably know about?

Comment: this command is effing dangerous in the hands of the sloppy. I ran it without the quotes around `+>` and ended up clobbering a file

Comment: Well, warnings we give based on our own mistakes are sorely bought, but theyre definitely worth a vote.

Comment: I would say "to view the file from the end" rather than
"in reverse" - 

    `</path/to/file tac | less`

would be "in reverse" to my ears.  Also

    `less +G /path/to/file` 

should be promoted over '+>" since it has the same effect with fewer
keystrokes and less danger of file clobbering for neophytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `less` specific (you can guess this with the quotes around the operator to avoid the shell interpreting it).  The `+` argument tells `less` to apply this command after opening the file, in this case `>` which is the keystroke for going to the end of the file.  You can try this out by opening some (long) file with `less` and hitting <kbd>></kbd>.  `+>` is just a shortcut for this.  A fairly more common use-case you'll find in the wild is calling `less +## /path/to/file` where `##` is a line number you want to be displayed by `less`.

At least `+##` also works for `vi` and `emacs`.

Comment: So '+' passes keystrokes to `less`? I mean i knew was escaped for a reason - as in - i knew it wasnt shell syntax, but often similar types of programs share common operators and such.

Comment: Actually a command.  Have a look at `man less | less '+/\+cmd'`. ;)

Comment: `man` answers are my favorite answers

Comment: My sarcasm sense tickles. I was proud of this since the exact command line also helps demonstrates what's going on.  When thinking about it further, commands and keystrokes in _less_ are rather equal.

Comment: No sarcasm - i must have said it in at least one other comment somewhere - look at the timing on my comment there and your first upvote. `man` answers *are* my favorite answers. And if you look at my own answers a lot of them are nothing but codeblocks at all.

Comment: Oh, that's an opinion I often miss here. ;) You might additionaly consider accepting the answer if it helped you (it's not just reputation points: it might help others with a similar question to find the answer more easily).

Comment: I am considering it - but the question's only 30 minutes old or so. Its a shame when we miss out on alternate information - if not necessarily better - just because the discussion dies out. If theres any to be had here id rather not squash it so soon.

Comment: That's, of course, perfectly reasonable and fine with me.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `less '+G' /the/file`  ? G also goes to the end of file (and there is less risk of clobbering the file you want to read!) ? (I can not test right now... no "less" at hand)

Comment: Yes, this also works (and you could even omit the quotes).  Would probably be the better way.

Answer (score 4):

A long long time ago, several programs understood the command line argument `+N` (e.g. `+42`) to mean “start at line *N*” (not “skip *N* lines”, but “skip *N*-1 lines”, because the first line is line 1). The oldest trace I can find is in [`tail`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tail&sektion=1&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition) in [Unix V7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix), but I don't know for sure that this is where the usage started. An important program with the same option is [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)). Other programs that inherited this syntax from more include [less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)), [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), and most other text editors today.

Over time, this syntax was progressively generalized. By 2.8BSD in 1980, [more](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=more&sektion=1&manpath=2.8+BSD) also supported `+/PATTERN` to start at the first line containing the specified pattern. By 2.10BSD in 1985, [vi](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vi&sektion=1&manpath=2.10+BSD) supported `+COMMAND` to run an arbitrary command on startup, generalizing `+/PATTERN` (not all versions of vi support this, and for example [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/vi.html) only specifies `-c COMMAND`, but it's supported by nvi, Elvis and Vim). The commands are [ex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) commands, i.e. what you can type after `:`.

Less also supports the generalized `+COMMAND` (I don't know since when, but it was in the 20th century). In the case of `+`, it's as if you'd typed the characters as input after less starts, except in the special cases `+N` which is equivalent to `+g` and `+/PATTERN` where you can omit the final <kbd>Return</kbd>.

`less '+>' /path/to/file` is an example of that usage: execute the command `>` (go to the end of the file) after startup. You can also write `less +G` since `G` and `>` are synonyms. You can combine commands, for example `less $'+>?foo\r' /path/to/file` to go to the last occurrence of `foo`.

Another way to make Less execute commands on startup is to stuff them in the `LESS` environment variable: `LESS='+>' less /path/to/file`. This is useful if `less` is invoked by another program such as `man` (example: [Reading and searching long man pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/reading-and-searching-long-man-pages/96231#96231)).

Comment: Actually `less $'+>?foo\r' /path/to/file` does not go to the last occurrence of `foo` if `foo` is present on the last screen because (according to `man less`) *The search starts at the line immediately before the top line displayed.* Btw, what's the purpose of `$` here?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost This seems to be an error in the manual: `?foo` searches backward from the *last* line on the screen. Experimentally, it only fails to go to the last occurrence if the last occurrence is on the last line. I don't know how to fix this. The purpose of using `$'…'` rather than `'…'` is to make the shell interpret backslash escapes: the shell sees `\r` and converts it to a carriage return character in the argument passed to `less`.

Comment: From what I see it also fails if the last occurrence is on the next to the last line. I have version 458 of less.