# how do I allow clobber in unix

Tags: command-line, set

I am in the bash shell, BSD unix, under macos, but I think this would apply to many other unix shells. The `noclobber` option can be useful at times:

```
> find . -name z
> set -o noclobber
> echo "dog" > z
> echo "dog" > z
-bash: z: cannot overwrite existing file
```

But how do I un-set it, without launching a new shell? 
Curiously, `bash undo set noclobber`, `unix un-do set noclobber`, and similar searches did not quickly bring up an answer.

None of the following work:

```
> unset -o noclobber
-bash: unset: -o: invalid option
unset: usage: unset [-f] [-v] [name ...]
> unset noclobber
> echo "dog" > z
-bash: z: cannot overwrite existing file
> set -o clobber
-bash: set: clobber: invalid option name
```

Answer (score 1):

One finds the answer at [How to undo `set -x`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149074/how-to-undo-set-x#149137), so that we have

```
> set +o noclobber
> echo "dog" > z
>
```

It is a bit counterintuitive: `+` turns something off; `-` turns it on.

And of course `unset noclobber` would just delete any variable I might have created which was named `noclobber`. That would have no effect on unix options.

Comment: Also, `echo dog >| z`